# How can I prevent direct access to custom error pages?

Tags: jsp, servlets, custom-error-pages

How can I disable direct access to my custom error page that is implemented using a servlet?

`web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app ...>
    <!-- ... -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ErrorPage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.example.ErrorPage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ErrorPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/custom-error-page</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <location>/custom-error-page</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

This configuration works for displaying error pages when there are errors. However, I am able to directly access the error page (e.g. at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/custom-error-page`), which is undesirable. Is there a way to prevent direct access to the error page?

To solve the problem, I thought about moving the code in `org.example.ErrorPage` to a JSP file (e.g. `errorpage.jsp`) placed in the `WEB-INF` directory, and configuring `web.xml` with:

```xml
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Although this successfully prevents users from directly accessing the error page, it is not ideal, because the JSP file would be littered by lots of Java code.

How can I prevent users from directly accessing error pages?

Comment: Putting in WEB-INF is the correct way. I only don't at all understand what you're referring to with *"because the JSP file would be littered by lots of Java code"*. Putting JSP files in WEB-INF doesn't require the JSP file being "littered by lots of Java code".

Comment: @BalusC It's just that I prefer having `*.java` files rather than `*.jsp` files.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding it. What's difficult with just putting Java code in Java files (such as servlets) instead of JSP files?

Comment: @BalusC If I place my custom error page in a Java file, the custom error page is directly accessible (as shown in first `web.xml` in the question). If I place my custom error page in a JSP file inside the `WEB-INF` directory, the custom error page is not directly accessible. I want to use Java files instead of JSP files, but I do not want the custom error pages to be directly accessible. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, mind blown. I guess you're ultimately trying to ask "How do I run a servlet when a custom JSP error page is opened?" ?

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I guess so.